# named range chart vba

Tags: excel, vba, charts, named-ranges

I'm trying to make multiple charts of previously created named ranges, but I simply can't get the VBA code to work when referring to a cell that contains the name of the Named Range.

It looks like this:

```
Sub Top25_Charts()

Sheets("Top25Graphs").Activate
Set peerDataSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top25History")
Set peerGraphSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top25Graphs")
Set peerGraphDataSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top25GraphsData")




Dim myDateRange As Range
'Dim myNamedRange As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim NumberPeers As Integer
Dim NLetters As String
Dim NNumber As Integer


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For i = 1 To 1


NumberPeers = peerDataSht.Cells(i + 30, 13)
NLetters = peerGraphDataSht .Cells(i + 30, 1)
CName = peerDataSht.Cells(i + 61, 2)
Set cht = peerGraphSht.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
Set myDateRange = peerGraphDataSht.Range("Graph_Date")


With cht
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = CName
.HasLegend = True
.Legend.Position = xlBottom


End With

For j = 1 To NumberPeers


NNumber = peerGraphDataSht .Cells(30, 1 + j)
num = peerDataSht.Cells(31, 1 + j)
PeerName = peerDataSht.Cells(61 + i, 1 + j)
'peerDataSht.Range(Cells(i + 30, 1 + j))
myNamedRange = NLetters & "_" & NNumber


With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.XValues = myDateRange
.Values = NLetters & "_" & NNumber
.Name = PeerName
End With

Next j


With cht.Parent
.Left = peerGraphSht.Range("B2").Left
.Top = peerGraphSht.Range("B2").Top
.Width = peerGraphSht.Range("B2:I2").Width
.Height = peerGraphSht.Range("B2:B16").Height
End With


Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

But, I can't refer to `NLetters` and `NNumber`. Two references, `NLetters` and `Nnumber`, contain the named ranges, so the named ranges are called `a_1`, `a_2` .... `z_6`.

The line `peerDataSht.Range(Cells(i + 30, 1 + j))` refers directly to the cell that contains the named range, but also can't be used.

So is it possible to refer to a cell that contains the name of the named range, or do I have to insert the named range directly in the code like in the date line `Set myDateRange = peerGraphDataSht.Range("Graph_Date")`? I have 151 named ranges so I would rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

First I would advice you to add `Option explicit` above your Subroutine, because that would prevent some typo's in the code, like `peerGraphDataSht .Cells`. It would also prevent undimmed variables, like `myNamedRange`.

Try to `dim myNamedRange as Range` and then change the line `myNamedRange = NLetters & "_" & NNumber` to `set myNamedRange = Range(NLetters & "_" & NNumber)`. Then the range should cover your needs.